# Multiple asynchronous string replace in RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In an Angular app I have:

- a text in which I want to translate several resource keys
- an array of resource keys `("IS_LESS_THAN", "IS_GREATER_THAN", etc...)`
- an array of languages `("EN, NL, FR", etc..)`
- a service that can translate a single resource key. The service facilitates that when the chosen language changes, it emits a new value through the observable.

Asynchronous is the complex part. I cannot do a simple string.replace() on the text with a for loop because that would only work in a synchronous way.

How can the translation be accomplished using RxJS?
I have the following code, but stuck at the end:

```js
    const text = '....... 3 IS_LESS_THAN 5 ........';
    const keys = ['IS_LESS_THAN', 'IS_GREATER_THAN', ....... ];

    const translatedText$ = of(keys).pipe(
       switchMap((key) =>
           this.localizationService.translate(key).pipe( // Will update its value when the current language changes
               map((value) => ({
                   // Store the original key/value combination to do the replace
                   key,
                   value,
               }))
         )
        // PROBLEM: How to replace each key in the text and return the result?
        // I tried reduce, but how to combine the accumulator and the value?
        reduce((acc, val) => {
            return val[0].replace(val[1], );
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than expected. The catch was to combine the translation results first, using `combineLatest`. From that point, all translations are available in a `substitutions` list in a single element of the observable. It is no longer needed to reduce multiple observable items:

```
    return combineLatest(
        keys.map((key) =>
            this.localizationService.translate(key)))
        ).pipe(map((substitutions) => replace(text, substitutions)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the initial seed value, which in your case is probably `text`.

```
reduce((translatedText, translation) => {
  return translatedText.replace(translation.key, translation.value);
}, text)
```

You should also think about changing `switchMap` to `mergeMap` if you want all of your keys to be translated: https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-switchmap-related-bugs/